# Arrays.sort(). Сортировка массива строк по длине

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

У меня такое странное задание: надо отсортировать массив строк по возрастанию длины, причем именно с использованием Arrays.sort(arr). Я сделал сортировку циклами но мне сказали что надо именно sort(), но у него нет перегрузки с String. Есть только странная фигня

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a,
            Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Наверно она нужна, ноя что-то не врубаюсь как она работает...
Объясните что значит:

```
<T>
```

и

```
Comparator<? super T>
```

Что за `T`?

Comment: T - тип элементов, Comparator - функция производящая сравнение, на основе которого определяется порядок элементов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс, где определяем порядок сравнения:

```
class StringLengthSort implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if(o1.length() > o2.length()){
            return 1;
        }else{
            if(o1.length() < o2.length()){
                return -1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

или через лямбды, код будет немного короче:

```
Comparator<String> comprator = (o1,o2) -> o1.length() - o2.length();
```

Тестируем:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] names = {"Deaaaaaaan", "Deaaan", "Deaaaaaaaan", "Dean", "Deaaaaaan", "Deaan", "Deaaaaaaaaan",  "Deaaaan", "Deaaaaan"}; 
    Comparator<String> stringLengthComparator = new StringLengthSort();
    for(String str : names){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    Arrays.sort(names, stringLengthComparator); // применяем сортировку
    System.out.println("\nотсортировано\n");
    for(String str : names){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Deaaaaaaan
Deaaan
Deaaaaaaaan
Dean
Deaaaaaan
Deaan
Deaaaaaaaaan
Deaaaan
Deaaaaan

отсортировано

Dean
Deaan
Deaaan
Deaaaan
Deaaaaan
Deaaaaaan
Deaaaaaaan
Deaaaaaaaan
Deaaaaaaaaan
```

Comment: Компараторы спасут мир :)

Comment: Большое спасибо! А скажите пожалуйста как по русски читается вот эта строчка (o1,o2) -> o1.length() - o2.length()

Comment: тоесть что делает эта пипка -> ? ))) простоите за моветон)))

Comment: Это лямбда выражение

Comment: @Павел, это лямбда выражение, если проще - анонимный метод.